# Google Analytics events to gather information from iframe chat

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics, livechat

I'm developing a website for my client. But I've never been too good with Google Analytics or JavaScript, so I've got a problem now.

One of the most important pages there is a page with livestream player and live chat. Unfortunately, they're both iframes from external domain.

My client is using *GamingLive.tv* and code for chat iframe looks like that (code for player is the same, but has only `/e/` instead of `/echat/`):

```
<iframe class="chat" src="http://alpha.gaminglive.tv/embed.html#/echat/CHANNEL_NAME" 
    frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

---

**My question is** - can I (and if yes, how?) use Google Analytics event tracking to send information about users typing in chat? I want to send information about number of posts and their length.

Comment: The problem here is not the iframe, the problem is the different domain, which is apparently not under your control. Cross domain javascript from arbitrary sources would be a big security issue, so this is not possible.

Comment: @EikePierstorff I was afraid of that. And I guess it's not possible to catch events like `onKeyPressed` from within iframe with JavaScript outside it? That's bad :(

Comment: Correct. You won't be able to get that data unless you can put code on that page (which it sounds like you can't). You can get a click event on when the user clicks on the iframe, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need here is [GA EVENTS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide)

So you can track the user click on your `iframe` (which is in your case is CHAT).

Comment: Yes, but clicks aren't enough for my case. Is it possible to configure events or JS to get keypress? (Enter is posting message in chat)

Comment: OH my gosh .. you wanna get the chat details huh ? That is not possible using GA, as far I know ..what about DB , isnt the chats are stored ?